# 1,5gb of data in internal (system data) - how can I delete?

Tags: internal-storage

it seems that I've got 1,5gb of data in internal (system data) - how can I delete?

Answer (score 0):

The internal-storage partition is formatted when you execute a factory reset.

Comment: actually "system data" is in diskusage app

Comment: To what partition does it refer?

Comment: `/system` is never wiped - as it is read-only there is no need to wipe it.

Comment: it's in internal

Comment: Then a factory reset should delete the files. Or you can locate them and delete them manually. If you are referring to the 'internal storage' of your phone (simply everything), this contains the system as well. But you shouldn't delete the system for obvious reasons.

Comment: that's not actual system, but categorized in settings as "other data"

Comment: it should be some apk files left behind, even though I unistalled these apps (miui ones or office etc.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the AOSP sources of the disk usage settings app the category `System` is `Everything else that hasn't already been attributed`.

In concrete the value is calculated based on the "Others" value minus the data occupied by apps that belong to the the other displayed categories.

This makes it very difficult to say what data is included in this category.

Anyway 1.5GB of system data is typical value for an Android phone. It is not necessary to take any actions.